# Error: [$compile:tplrt] Template for directive 'footer' must have exactly one root element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Error**: 
angular.js:13920 Error: [$compile:tplrt] Template for directive 'footer' must have exactly one root element. app/components/footer/views/footer.html

I'm trying to call the footer by a directive without being over ng include. He is giving a root error but the path is right. I'm not understand why this error.
I not try my header yet but probably have the same error.

Index:

```
<div footer> </div>
```

Footer:

```
<!-- Footer Section -->
<section class="services-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="col-sm-3 logotipos">
                    <img src="../../../../assets/img/logotipos/blip.png" width="185" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 logotipos">
                    <img src="../../../../assets/img/logotipos/farfetch.png" width="185" />
                </div> 
                <div class="col-sm-3 logotipos">
                    <img src="../../../../assets/img/logotipos/mobintec.png" width="185" />
                </div>        
                <div class="col-sm-3 logotipos">
                    <img src="../../../../assets/img/logotipos/rumos.png" width="185" />
                </div>                                                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- Footer Section -->
<section class="contact-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8">
                <ul class="list-inline quicklinks">
                    <li><a href="#" style="color: white;">Eventos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" style="color: white;">Dicas</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" style="color: white;">Contactos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" style="color: white;">Parceiros</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" style="color: white;">Termos e Condições</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" style="color: white;">Políticas de Privacidade</a></li>
                </ul>
                <p style="text-align: left; clear: both; color: white; font-size: 12px;">Copyright @ 2016 Todos os direitos reservados</p>             
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <ul class="list-inline quicklinks redes_sociais">
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="../../../../assets/img/redessociais/instagram.png" width="25" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="../../../../assets/img/redessociais/twitter.png" width="25" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="../../../../assets/img/redessociais/linkedin.png" width="25" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><img src="../../../../assets/img/redessociais/facebook.png" width="25" /></a></li>
                </ul>                
            </div>                
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

App:

```
app.directive('footer', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A', //This menas that it will be used as an attribute and NOT as an element. I don't like creating custom HTML elements
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: "app/components/footer/views/footer.html",
        controller: "footer"
    }
});
```

controller footer

```
'use strict';
/**
 * Clip-Two Main Controller
 */
app.controller("footer", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.page = "ola footer";
    console.log("teste = ".$scope.page);

}]);
```

Comment: what does the HTML in `footer.html` look like?

Comment: What does `footer.html` look like?

Comment: you have two `<section>` elements here, each one a "root" element.  try wrapping the whole thing in a `<div>`.

Comment: alternatively, you can just remove `replace: true`;  not only is it not necessary in your code, it is also deprecated anyway.

Comment: if i delete replace: true it's work :) but my $scope.page dont print nothing for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs at : https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tplrt

> When a directive is declared with template (or templateUrl) and
>   replace mode on, the template must have exactly one root element. That
>   is, the text of the template property or the content referenced by the
>   templateUrl must be contained within a single html element.

hence include your code in a div or some other element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the html in `footer.html` with a single element so that there is only one root element.

```
<div>
... your markup
</div>
```

This is required since you're using replace. Here are more details from the [angular error docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/tplrt).